# model.find({}) in mongoose not giving output of db.model.find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Need some help, I have the following schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

Then I have an array:

```
var categories = ['Men\'s', 'Women\'s', 'Children\'s', 'Baby\'s'];
```

Then I run :

```
async function addCats() {
    try {
        for (const category of categories){
            Category.create({name:category});
            console.log("Created Category: " + category)
        }
        console.log(Category.find({}));
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

And the console.log for the Category.find({}) returns some crazy object.

However if I go into mongo and I do db.categories.find() I Get the right data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4742899146fc1c2bb9837e"), "name" : "Women's", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4742899146fc1c2bb9837d"), "name" : "Men's", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4742899146fc1c2bb98380"), "name" : "Baby's", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4742899146fc1c2bb9837f"), "name" : "Children's", "__v" : 0 }
```

I feel like I am making some stupid mistake but cant figure it out.

Comment: `console.log(await Category.find({}));` or `const categories = await Category.find({});`

Comment: Mongoose's find is async, mongodb shell's find is not. That's what you're missing.

Comment: Yeah this was just for debugging a problem I was having with async code then forgot to add the callback for this thanks! Dont know why id printed such a hughe object though, it was like a bunch of info from the mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the callback function for `find()`. You should use something like,

```
Category.find({}, function(err, result){
   console.log(result);
})
```

Your final code becomes:

```
async function addCats() {
  try {
    for (const category of categories){
      Category.create({name:category});
      console.log("Created Category: " + category)
    }
    Category.find({}, function(err, result){
      console.log(result);
    }); 
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this was just for debugging a problem I was having with async code and forgot about part here, thanks!

Comment: @Jack glad to help

Comment: Do you know why it printed out such a weird object??? What it was ??? it was like all the info in mongo

Comment: It was a promise object from mongodb

Comment: Ah I see, sorry to bug Ankit but I really want to learn this stuff, why would not having a callback make it return a promise??

Comment: Because that is a asynchronous function and it waits for the result. So, you were just console logging the function.